# this or base? In which case could we use base instead of this?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

In the following code

```
// MVVM Views part class
public partial class DashBoard : UserControl
{
    public DashBoard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new DashBoardViewModel();
    }
}
```

Could we use base.DataContext instead this.DataContext. In which case could we use base instead of this?

Comment: Of course, to avoid confusion you could use *neither* too - just `DataContext = ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually clearer to use `this`. You normally only specify `base` when you want to explicitly call a base class constructor or the base implementation of an overridden method or property.

Using `base.DataContext` would *work*, but it would might imply that `this.DataContext` would mean something different.

Answer (score 2):

You use `this` to access a method defined in the present class (or superclass if it's not in the present class). You use `base` to access a method in the superclass or higher. In this case you could have used either (or none as Marc points out above).

I prefer to emit `this` except when it's (rarely) required.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what the others have said, base. is used when you've overridden something from the base class with either the overrides or new keywords, you'll need to use base to gain access to the original method.

```
class a
{
   public virtual void method1()
   {
   }

   public string property1 { get; set; }
}

class b : a
{
    // this has it's own instance in b, the only way to get to
    // the original property1 is with base (or reflection)
    public new string property1 { get; set; }

    public override void method1()
    {
       // the only way to get to the original method1 and property1
       base.method1();
       base.property1 = "string";
    }
}
```

In your example if the DataContext property uses either of these keywords then base and this don't mean the same thing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your case u are trying to initialize **DataContext** property of class **DashBoard** with some value. So if you then call **DataContext** typed property of **(base)UserControl** class object, it still will be not initialized. Therefore, to decide which property to initialize, u must to look to your program's logic.

Basicly MSDN tells that u should use (base.) in two scenarious:
-Call a method on the base class that has been overridden by another method.
-Specify which base-class constructor should be called when creating instances of the derived class.
In my practise i used first scenario when (this) method ends with exception, i was trying to call more general (base) method. Good luck!